# Issue with jquery offset() of the same element within 2 differnet sidebars

Tags: jquery, offset

As I am new to js I can't solve a problem with offset() by myself.

I got two sidebars - one on the left, the other one on the right. In the DOM, the left one comes first.

Within my sidebars I have the the following structure:

```
<div class="sidebar-inner">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        Some blabla
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-content">
        More blabla
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
        Also some blabla
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I try to get the position of my "sidebar-header" with jquery by clicking an element in my sidebar.

```
$('.cssClass1, .cssClass2').on('click', function (){
   var position = $('.sidebar-header').offset();
            
      if (position.top < 0){
         console.log('unvisible');
      } else {
         console.log('visible')
      };

});
```

With my code, I got the position, but just from my "sidebar-header" which comes first in the DOM (the left sidebar, in this case).

How can I get the position of my "sidebar-header" within the sidebar from where the cssClass element is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `closest` method, to find closest ancestor?

```
$('.cssClass1, .cssClass2').on('click', function () {
    const position = $(this).closest('.sidebar-inner').find('.sidebar-header').offset();

    if (position.top < 0) {
        console.log('unvisible');
    } else {
        console.log('visible');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this perfectly works for my needs!

Answer (score 0):

If there are several elements, then you need to use a `.each()`:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  $('.sidebar-inner').each(function(){
    const { top } = $(this).offset();
    console.log(top);
  })
})
```

```css
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 100px;
}

.sidebar-inner:last-child {
  margin-top: 40px;
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
  <div class="sidebar-inner">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      Some blabla
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      More blabla
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      Also some blabla
    </div>
  </div>
  <main></main>
  <div class="sidebar-inner">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      Some blabla
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-content">
      More blabla
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      Also some blabla
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Get Sidebars Offset</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. This (of course) works also and gives me back 4 top values. Each for every 'sidebar-inner'.  

So, if I am right, now I could set a class to the .sidebar-inner which is top < 0 and start another function by searching for this class.